# How to render multiple views by using bonfire admin controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, bonfire

My codeigniter application consists of an admin panel(developed using bonfire) and a front application which shows different products . Admin panel is working perfectly. But i want to use bonfire assets management feature(like merging all css & jss file into one , minification)  of bonfire in my front application .

I have three different view(header.php, body.php & footer.php) files which i want to render it by extending admin controller of bonfire.

```
    //Via codeigniter it can be achieved like this
    class Home extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
             //By using codeigniter load view 
             $this->load->view('header');
             $this->load->view('body');
             $this->load->view('footer');
        }
    }

        //Extending Bonfire Admin controller 
        class Home extends Admin_Controller
        {
            public function index()
            {
                 //How to do this ?
            }
        }
```

More information related to bonfire layout http://cibonfire.com/docs/developer/layouts_and_views

More information related to bonfire assets management http://cibonfire.com/docs/developer/working_with_assets

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: i don't know how bonefire works, but you can load one view which will load your three views.

Comment: @AdrienXL I want to do this because my header.php contains so many css and js files which i want to merge into one css and one js by using bonfire assets management functions .

Can't merge all three files into one as it changes based on product information.